# Will only hassan and hussain be masters of youth in paradise?

Tags: hadith, hadith-interpretation, revelation, hussain

The hadith reported by Ahmad, At-Tirmithi, Ibn Maajah and An-Nasaa’i, it was narrated by Abu Sa’eed Al-Khudri  may  Allaah  be  pleased  with  him who said: “The Prophet  sallallaahu  `alayhi  wa  sallam ( may  Allaah exalt his mention ) said: **''Al-Hasan and Al-Husayn are the masters of the youth of Paradise.”** Shaykh Al-Albaani  may  Allaah  have  mercy  upon  him classified it as Saheeh [sound].

The hadith doesnt negate other people from holding the title  "masters of youth". The hadith doesnt rule out third son of Ali and fatima, muhsin. Provided there is consensus (ijma) which says **muhsin will be in paradise**.

Imaam al-Nawawi said: the reliable Muslim scholars agreed that **any Muslim child who dies will be among the people of Paradise,** because he was not responsible (i.e., had not yet reached the age of account). (Sharh Muslim, 16/207).

So the question is do we have other masters of youth in paradise?

Answer (score 1):

Asalaam Alaikum

this hadith clearly states who are the masters of youth in paradise, like you mentioned it dosen't negate others holding the same titile but there is no authentic evidence to prove that there are other masters of the youth in paradise. i will try to clarify a little more so that you could understand better, insha Allah.

the arabic word used in this hadith is ‘شباب’. the commentators explain that this refers to those who are of thirty years of age [and below]. since the inhabitants of paradise are of equal age, i have found commentators explaining this in three ways.

01- Hasan and Husayn (radiyallahu ‘anhuma) are the leaders/the best of all those who passed away as youth in the path of Allah.

02- they will be the leader of all the inhabitants of paradise with the exception of the prophets and the rightly guided caliphs.

03- Currently [i.e. when prophet (sallallahu ‘alayhi wa sallam) uttered this], they are the leaders of all those youngsters who are destined for paradise.

(refference: Mirqatul Mafatih, Hadith: 6163 and Tuhfatul Ahwadhi, Hadith: 3768)

i believe it is worthy to mention that there are authentic hadith mentioning "leaders/chiefs of middle aged" and "leader/chief of women" in paradise. so this hadith also must be taken in the same vein as others referring to the same concept.

may Allah grant you mercy and guide you to the straight path.

Allah knows best.

Comment: You said rightly guided caliphs, what about remaining 6 of the best 10 among this ummah. Ashraful mubashirrat

Comment: it is not my personal opinion, i have taken references from the two books Mirqatul Mafatih and Tuhfatul Ahwadhi to clarify your question. there are authentic hadith about the superiority of the four rightly guided caliphs, more than that i do not know for now.